# Combine 2 csv file with new row in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 2 csv file

1)

```
CustomerID
ID001
ID002
ID003
ID004
ID005
ID006
ID007
ID008
ID009
```

[image]

2.

```
MiniID
1001
1002
1003
1005
1006
1007
1008
1009
1010
```

[image]

How can I combine them together in 1 single Csv file? **Note**: I do not want to specific which column to combine, I just want the new data to be combine with the first csv file.
I had tried to combine them but the new added value is showing at the bottom instead beside it.

[image]

My code

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("C:/Users/crayx/PycharmProjects/xxx/Csv")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Comment: do you the same number of entries in both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column in the original dataframe with the content of the column of the second dataframe. Something like this:

```
my_csvs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames]
my_csv = my_csvs[0]
for csv in my_csvs[1:]:
    for column in csv.columns:
        my_csv[column] = csv[column]
```

PS: code has not been tested

Answer (score 2):

Try adding axis=1 as the paramter. Because the pd.concat cancats the two dataframe on the axis=0 by default

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use concat try to add `axis=1` and `ignore_index=True` as it in documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)